# how to make a http post request on server side after data insert in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to understand AWS data sync on xamarin. they have a nice SDK to use in xamarin.forms. I am using onesignal notifications instead of aws notifications. 
my question is I want to fire a notification after a data insert or sync. Onesignal has an api working with http post.
So how do I make post to onesignal endpoint when

1. user data is syncronized with aws cognito
2. a new shared data is inserted into DynamoDB

Of course I can do that on clientside but this is not a good practice. I would like to do that on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you can use [Cognito events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html), which execute a Lambda function, whenever the data is synchronized by the user. In this Lambda function you can fire the notification.

For #2, I do not see how that is related to Cognito Sync, as the data is stored in datasets not DynamoDB. If you are talking idependently about data being inserted into DynamoDB and getting notified about that, then again [DynamoDB has nice integration with AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) to send notifications on table updates.

Comment: thanks for answering. They were 2 separate questions as I target to use both. Those Lambda functions are node.js functions, right?

Comment: AWS Lambda supports code written in Node.js (JavaScript), Python, Java (Java 8 compatible), and C# (using the .NET Core runtime). 

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/